# Python- How can I output Square roots instead of numbers with finite decimal part

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am writing a code in Python 2.7 that calculates the root of a quadratic equation. However the outputs are of the form 1.41421356237 for example.... Is there a way to produce its square root form (sqrt(2))?

Here is my code:

```
from __future__ import division
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy
import scipy.special as sp
import scipy.integrate as integrate
import pylab as pylab
import math
import cmath

alpha = input('Enter alpha: ')
c = 1/alpha
a = 1
b = 1
d = b**2 - 4*a*c

if d<0:
    s1 = (-b+cmath.sqrt(d)) / (2*a)
    s2 = (-b-cmath.sqrt(d)) / (2*a)
    print "Two Complex Solutions: ",s1, " and",s2
elif d==0:
    s = (-b+math.sqrt(d))/ (2*a)
    print "One real solution: ",s
else:
    s1 = (-b+math.sqrt(d)) / 2*a
    s2 = (-b-math.sqrt(d)) / 2*a
    print "Two real solutions: ",s1," and",s2
```

This is an example of the output which i need in square root form:

```
Enter alpha: 6
Two real solutions:  -0.211324865405  and -0.788675134595
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python by default is eager evaluation.
It means at the moment you applied sqrt to number eg. sqrt(2).
It has already lost its symbolic meaning and replaced with real number.

To get what you need, you can redefine you function to work on string instead 
so that python interpreter won't try to evaluate it to number.

```
s1 = "-{b}+sqrt({d})/2*{a}".format(b=b,d=d,a=a)
s2 = "-{b}-sqrt({d})/2*{a}".format(b=b,d=d,a=a)
```

The part of code above will produce a string in symbolic from instead of number.

Comment: That was very useful ... Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of `Sympy` module! It is made for things like this.

For your case, you can use `sympy.sqrt` instead of `cmath.sqrt` to get the square root representation. Example:

```
import sympy
sympy.sqrt(8) # Output: 2*sqrt(2)
sympy.sqrt(8) * sympy.sqrt(3) # Output: 2*sqrt(6)
```

[Here](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/tutorial/intro.html) you can find an introduction to the module.

Comment: It seems that i dont have sympy on my mac. Is there any detailed explanation how to install it ? I am new to programming and mac world !! Also i use Sublime Text 3

Comment: Sure! Open Terminal on your mac (in Applications(/utilities) i think) and then type: `pip install sympy` on it. If you get an error containing `Permission denied` try doing: `sudo pip install sympy`.

Comment: Sorry for asking alot, but that is what i am getting: sudo: pip: command not found

Comment: This means you don't have `pip` installed. To install it you need to follow two simple steps found in [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/). Once installed, run the command specified above

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at symbolic computation with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SymPy .